# Disable mount for internal HDDs

Tags: automount, udev

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu (I'm using 12.04) and I am looking for a way to make it so that when I boot from my USB stick the internal HDDs of the computer I'm using dont mount. I would also like to know if there is a good way to force all mounts to default as read only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit `/etc/fstab` of the booting system. 
To have your HDD not automounted when you but from USB stick, add one line for each partition, such as:

```
/dev/hda1 / auto noauto 0 0
```

To have it mounted in readonly mode:

```
/dev/hda1 / auto ro 0 0
```

A complete manual for fstab is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab), otherwise just google around!

Comment: Will this work if you don't know how many partitions there will be or what their filesystems are ahead of time?

Comment: All partitions should be listed in fstab to be mounted. You can't add wildcards or refer to all present partitions with a single line but you could not list anything: in this case nothing will be mounted.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it best to use udev rules to ignore the HDD you want to ignore.

From [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.freedesktop.telepathy/5190) serverfault answer:

---

As root, open up /etc/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules with your favorite text editor.

A few lines down, you'll probably see a line that looks like this:

# skip rules for inappropriate block devices
KERNEL=="ram*|loop*|fd*|nbd*|gnbd*|dm-*|md*", GOTO="persistent_storage_end"
Add "sdb*" to that second line, so it looks like this:

KERNEL=="ram*|loop*|fd*|nbd*|gnbd*|dm-*|md*|sdb*", GOTO="persistent_storage_end"
Save the file and then reboot.

---

ErikA didn't have his system available to test this advice, and unfortunately I'm using a friends computer myself.

Many devices are now discovered by udev rather than relying on /etc/fstab, and that includes hard disks. Note that you may have to *change sdb to the device you want to ignore* (sda ?)

The udev man page has more information on udev rules, including how to change device permissions, which may be a good way to make such a device read-only.